# How to display the images from url in tableview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I am using the following code to display the images in the table view,

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[xmlParser templates] count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Temp *currentTemplate = [[xmlParser templates] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        CGRect contentNameLabelFrame = CGRectMake(64, 2, 250, 20);
        UILabel *contentNameLabelF = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentNameLabelFrame];
        contentNameLabelF.tag = 0011;
        contentNameLabelF.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        contentNameLabelF.text = @"Template Name:";
        contentNameLabelF.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentNameLabelF];

        CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(115, 2, 250, 20);
        UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];
        contentLabel.tag = 0012;
        contentLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentLabel];



        CGRect contentnumberofcontacts = CGRectMake(63, 20, 250, 13);
        UILabel *contentnumberofcontactsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentnumberofcontacts];
        contentnumberofcontactsLabel.tag = 0013;
        contentnumberofcontactsLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
        contentnumberofcontactsLabel.text = @"Image:";
        contentnumberofcontactsLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentnumberofcontactsLabel];

        CGRect contentnumberFrame = CGRectMake(115, 20, 250, 13);
        UILabel *contentnumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentnumberFrame];
        contentnumberLabel.tag = 0014;
        contentnumberLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentnumberLabel];


        CGRect contentstatus = CGRectMake(78, 35, 250, 10);
        UILabel *contentstatuslabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentstatus];
        contentstatuslabel.tag = 0015;
        contentstatuslabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
        contentstatuslabel.text = @"Category:";
        contentstatuslabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentstatuslabel];

        CGRect statusFrame = CGRectMake(115, 35, 250, 10);
        UILabel *statusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusFrame];
        statusLabel.tag = 0016;
        statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:statusLabel];



    }

    UILabel *contentLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0012];
    contentLabel.text = [currentTemplate templateName];

    UILabel *contentnumberLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0014];
    contentnumberLabel.text = [currentTemplate imagePath];

    UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0016];
    statusLabel.text = [currentTemplate category];



    return  cell;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    return 75;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    xmlParser = [[ViewController alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.xxxxx.net/xxxxx/xxxx.aspx?type=xxxxx&xxxx="];
}

-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _templates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];

    return self;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"template_maste"])
    {
        currentTemplate = [Temp alloc];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"img_path"])
    {
        currentTemplate = [Temp alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Template_name"])
    {
        currentTemplate.templateName = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"img_path"])
    {
        currentTemplate.imagePath = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Category"])
    {
        currentTemplate.category = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"template_maste"])
    {
        [self.templates addObject:currentTemplate];
        currentTemplate = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

I am able to display the path of the image in the tableView, but i need to display the images in the tableView from the url.

I searched for the solution, but i was not able to get the solution,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta make a url request for allt he images' URLs. Instead of UILabel, put an UIImageView, and load image data from url response into the imageview.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ASIHTTPRequest` you can do this like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/picture.png"];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];
    [self.myImageView setImage:img];
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

**EDIT:** I also suggest you to save downloaded images (with names like URL_MD5.png) on device and fetch them from Internet only if they missed in your cache. Also you could create a 'component' based on UIImageView that shows activity indicator (like ajax) until download complete. So you could add a method like `loadImageFromUrl` that will look image in the cache and asynchroniously load it if needed, store it to cache and show it after all.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get all the image URLs. Try the following code to display it!! :-)

```
NSString *imageStr = [imageURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *trimmedString = [imageStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *string1=[trimmedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/n" withString:@""];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string1];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image = newImage;
```

Comment: But this blocks the UI as all the calls are sync in nature.

Comment: dataWithContentsOfURL is a synchronous method which is blocked untill the entire contents are fetched, thereby blocking the UI. Hence we need to resort to Async download and update in the main thread after download is complete. Hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: I understand the problem. So what sort of modification I ought to do to achieve this?

Comment: Troolee's answer would be my preferred method. If you can't use external implementations then you can write a async method and upload the imageview. Also you can have a look at https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
NSString *path = @"http://www.yoururl/images/yourimage.png";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img] autorelease];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
[cell addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to Teodor's answer, using [AFNetworking framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) will help your life. It works with block based methods. More helpful, it has AFImageRequestOperation, a specific class for downloading and processing images, and UIImageView+AFNetworking, that can help you even more loading remote images asynchronously.